# Extract numbers from NSString

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

How can I extract numbers from a string defined like:

```
NSString *getNumber = @"Price138.50 Code112.250"
```

I need to extract both `138.50` and `112.25` from this string.

Comment: You may want to look into `Regex`

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSScanner`, slightly modified from [this Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html):

```
NSCharacterSet *numberCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-"];
NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
while (![theScanner isAtEnd]) {
    // Eat non-digits and negative sign
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numberCharset
                               intoString:NULL];
    float aFloat;     
    if ([theScanner scanFloat:&aFloat]) {
        NSLog(@"Found %f", aFloat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,  does scanner treat 138.50 as float ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I don't see why not.  Do you think not then?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes, it does.

Comment: I have no idea how scanner works. I was just asking to confirm it. Cool it does!!

Comment: Good, that you edited the code to scan up for the digits. As a little note: If the product(? It seems to be a product.) is a rabat code, it can have a minus sign. Therefore using `-decimalDigitsCharacterSet:` might not work. But for the example it surely works.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad That is a good point and something I had not considered.  I may well try and think about a solution to that.

Comment: No problem. If this is the case, `+characterSetWithCharactersFromString:` (or so) should work

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad  Hehe; already sorted :)  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -5):

```
NSString *getNumber = @"Price138.50 Code112.250";
getNumber = [getNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Price" withString:@""];
getNumber = [getNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Code" withString:@""];
getNumber = [getNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@","];
NSArray *values = [getNumber componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"Price Value: %@", [values firstObject]);
NSLog(@"Code Value: %@", [values lastObject]);
```

If your string will be of same kind then this can be a possible way. **Not Recommended.**

Comment: I'm confused about why you would post an answer that you don't recommend using.

Comment: @AaronBrager, because, sometimes wrong techniques is much better than then right one. :) If I would him, I bet to use this as its first comes to my mind as the easiest way to get this done.